# Plus and minus button (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I have tried out the add and minus button.

The thing i am trying to do is if i have selected 10 bus tickets, then how do i write a javascript function to limit the maximum of the input. For instance, if adult is increment by 1, then the maximum input for the child will be changed into 9.

Here is my code

```js
function myFunction() {
  var adult = document.getElementByID("adult").value;
  var child = document.getElementByID("child").value;
  var maxAdult = document.getElementByID("adult").max;
  var maxChild = document.getElementByID("child").max;
  if (adult + 1) {
    maxChild = -1;
  }
  if (adult + 1) {
    maxAdult = -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="input-group" style="width: 150px;margin: 20px;">
  <span class="input-group-btn"> <!--  This is for adult tickets -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number"  data-type="minus" data-field="quant1">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
  </button>
  </span>
  <input type="text" name="quant1" id="adult" class="form-control input-number" value="0" min="0" max="<?php echo 10 ?>" onchange="myFunction()">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="quant1">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  </button>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="input-group" style="width: 150px;margin: 20px;">
  <span class="input-group-btn"> <!-- This is for child tickets -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number"  data-type="minus" data-field="quant1">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
  </button>
  </span>
  <input type="text" name="quant1" id="adult" class="form-control input-number" value="0" min="0" max="<?php echo 10 ?>" onchange="myFunction()">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="quant1">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  </button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: what JS have you written so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO!, Can you please provide minimal working example ?

Comment: I made you a snippet. You can edit it by clicking edit, then scroll down and click "edit above snippet" please paste in JS you used and choose relevant frameworks

Comment: You need to assign `onchange` event listeners to the `<input>`s. In those, read the values and adjust them accordingly.

Comment: Is my JS function written correctly? Lets assume that the maximum is 10 which is get from previous form when i purchases 10 tickets.

Comment: Please follow instructions when I suggest you update the snippet. I did it for you now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const all_count = 10;
let adult_count = 0;
let child_count = 0;

$('.btn-number').on("click", function() {
  let role = $(this).closest("div").attr("id");
  let type = $(this).attr("data-type");

  switch (role) {
    case 'adult':
      switch (type) {
        case 'plus':
          if ((adult_count + child_count) < all_count)
            adult_count++;
          break;
        case 'minus':
          if (adult_count != 0)
            adult_count--;
          break;
      }
      $('#adult_input').val(adult_count);
      break;
    case 'child':
      switch (type) {
        case 'plus':
          if ((adult_count + child_count) < all_count)
            child_count++;
          break;
        case 'minus':
          if (child_count != 0)
            child_count--;
          break;
      }
      $('#child_input').val(child_count);
      break;
  }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h4>This is for adult tickets</h4>
    <div id="adult">
      <span class="input-group-btn"> 
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number"  data-type="minus" data-field="quant1">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
      </button>
      </span>
      <input type="text" name="quant1" id="adult_input" class="form-control input-number" value="0" min="0" max="5">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="quant1">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
      </button>
      </span>
    </div>

    <h4>This is for child tickets</h4>
    <div id="child">
      <span class="input-group-btn"> 
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number"  data-type="minus" data-field="quant1">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
      </button>
      </span>
      <input type="text" name="quant1" id="child_input" class="form-control input-number" value="0" min="0" max="5">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="quant1">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
      </button>
      </span>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You snippet has some errors for example child input has same id. but easiest way to make dynamic max be attache event on adult input

```html
<input type="number" name="quant1" id="adult" class="form-control input-number" value="0" min="0" max="5" onchange="document.getElementById('child').max = 10 - e.target.value">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code.

```js
$("#adultMinus").click(function() {
  $("#child").val(0);
  if (parseInt($("#adult").val()) != 0) {
    let result = parseInt($("#adult").val()) - 1;
    $("#adult").val(result);       
    let maxLimit = 10 - parseInt($("#adult").val());
    $("#child").attr({
      "max": maxLimit,
    });
  }
})
$("#adultPlus").click(function() {
  $("#child").val(0);
  let result = parseInt($("#adult").val()) + 1;
  $("#adult").val(result);
  let maxLimit = 10 - parseInt($("#adult").val());
  $("#child").attr({
    "max": maxLimit,
  });
})
$("#childMinus").click(function() {
  if (parseInt($("#child").val()) != 0) {
    let result = parseInt($("#child").val()) - 1;
    $("#child").val(result);
  }
})
$("#childPlus").click(function(event) {
  var maxLength = parseInt($("#child").attr("max"));
  let result = parseInt($("#child").val()) + 1;
  if (result > maxLength) {
    alert("Max child limit is: "+maxLength);
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  } else {
    $("#child").val(result);
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <lable>Adult Ticket Count: </lable>
  <button id="adultMinus" class="btn btn-danger">-</button>
  <input type="number" name="quant1" id="adult" value="0" min="0">
  <button id="adultPlus" class="btn btn-success">+</button>

</div><br/><br/>
<div class="container">
  <lable>Child Ticket Count: </lable>
  <button id="childMinus" class="btn btn-danger">-</button>
  <input type="number" style="min-width:160px" name="quant1" id="child" value="0" min="0">
  <button id="childPlus" class="btn btn-success">+</button>

</div>
```